# PHP PDO Query not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know the values are correct because I tested them, I know the query works in the console - But I am pulling my hair out trying to see how this is not working. I don't get any errors, but the `var_dump($row)` === false.

Can you see where I am going wrong?

```
<?php
include('config.php');
//include('classes/db.class.php');
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['cart_id']);
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST .';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
if(isset($_POST['add2cart']))
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_id']))
        $_SESSION['cart_id'] = md5(my stuff here);
    try{
        $stmt = $db->prepare("
            SELECT *
            FROM cart
            WHERE cart_id = ':cartid'
            AND sku = ':sku'
        ");
        $stmt->bindParam(':cartid', $_SESSION['cart_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':sku', $_POST['sku'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        //print_r($stmt);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        var_dump($row);
    } catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you do another query it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should remove the single quotes around the parameter name. What it does is it basically changes into the parameter name into a string literal,

```
SELECT *
FROM cart
WHERE cart_id = :cartid AND sku = :sku
```

Comment: OMG, im such an idiot! Thank you so much JW!

Comment: In the binding you give the type, the pdo binding converts it automatically into quotes ( or not if its a int )

Comment: Yep was going to, but had to wait like 11 minutes or something :/ Wil do so now though, thank you